# Multiple hypothesis test

Tags: p-value, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate, adjustment

I have some questions about multiple hypothesis test.
Situation 1: We have 1000 p-values, all of them are less than 0.0 5. We may say there are 50 false positive (1000*0.05) in these p-values.
Situation 2: We have 1000 p-values, all of them are greater than 0.05. Can we still say there are 50 false positive in the p-values. Apparently, it is unreasonable. Because there are not positive in these p-values.
Multiple hypothesis test is used to control false positive. So the premise is that we must have positive. 
Together, I think the adjustment object is the p values those are less than 0.05, not all the p-values including p-values >0.05.
I am not sure my though is wrong or right?
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The theory about Type I errors states that at $\alpha=0.05$, **on average**, you can expect about 5 % of hypotheses to be false positives, but since this is an average it could also happen for ex., that you have 0 % false positives or 10 % false positives or any another number (which is unknown).

If, as in your example, all your p-values are greater than 0.5 then you can definitely claim that you have no false positives. In the example where all the p-values are less than 0.5 then you can expect about 5 % of them to be false positives (on average).

Sample size does affect this measure, the bigger the sample the better this estimate approaches $\alpha$ (less variability around its predefined value).